# How can I make files created / downloaded by my app show up in the Files application?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I managed to download files and save them inside the the document directory, however I can't access them from the Files app (the file manager).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add following permissions in info.plist

> ```
> Application supports iTunes file sharing  = yes
> Supports opening documents in place  = yes
> ```

[image]

Comment: The above setup will allow  me to access documents directory from iPhone?

Comment: Just now I tried, I don't see any option to open directory from iPhone file manager

Comment: in your phone's file manager and in it open `on my iphone` you can see the files or directory inside of document directory

Comment: Whether we need to get any permission from user?. I selected `on my iPhone` option, it list only local files not document directory files.